# What is the Industry Best Practice for Updating Dell Drivers ?

Tags: dell, drivers, best-practices

Is it ok to upgrade to latest drivers whenever we provide it to end-user ? or we should keep the Drivers with OS which has been shipped by Dell along with OS

Kindly suggest if there is any document or blog from Dell about it as well

Comment: What does it mean: "Whenever we provide it to end-user?" What are you doing with these servers?

Comment: My answer to the question as it is currently phrased would be to always use the version of the driver that `apt-get dist-upgrade` installs.

Answer (score 2):

The drivers on Dell's website should always have a 'classification', such as Recommended or optional to help an IT department decide whether or not driver updates should be applied.

Ultimately, though, it's going to come down to business procedures and policies such as different compliance frameworks, etc to figure out if updates are needed.

As an aside: I always update drivers before deploying a computer unless there are known issues.  I only do BIOS updates if there are security issues or bug fixes for problems we are having.